# jQuery Autosize - Use callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, autosize

I use [jQuery Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) and I can not figure out, how to use callback. Here is my attempt:

```
$('#selector').autosize({callback: function myfunc()});

function myfunc() {
    alert("Lorem ipsum");
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Probably that you're redeclaring `myfunc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#selector').autosize({callback: myfunc});

function myfunc() {
    alert("Lorem ipsum");
}
```

This should work, before you were declaring two functions : the first `myfunc` in the callback object, that was empty, and the second `myfunc` with the alert, but that was never called as the two functions are different.

Also, prefer using `console.log` instead of `alert`, it does not block the web page and it is more discrete.